# Why is not the new Visual Studio runtime part of Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know that I have to distribute C / C++ runtime libraries along with my project. I am just wondering why Microsoft does not do that for us? I know that there is Visual Studio 6.0 runtime included in Windows but why there is no new one?

If somebody could give me a link to some explanation article. I am trying to google that without success for a while.

Comment: The VC++ 6 runtime was only included sort of incidentally, because they included some programs that had been compiled with VC++6 that needed it. A similar program developed today is more likely to depend on (some version of) .NET.

Comment: +1 for a good point; seems intrusive to the user. Not to mention confusing to a non-programmer trying to install your program: "What the hell is this C++ Runtime garbage?!"

Comment: Windows is [not a delivery channel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/11/7065021.aspx) for DLLs you need.  Nor could that ever work in practice, your customer isn't going to update his Windows version just because you upgraded your compiler.

Comment: I would assume that if it is an operating system from Microsoft they can distribute those DLLs as a standard part of their operating system. If you install those DLLs they are going to be updated by Windows Update.

Comment: @jhruby: Microsoft already distributes a "VC++ runtime distributable" which you may include in your installer. Available both as .EXE and .MSI IIRC

Comment: @MSalters I know that. I have no problem to distribute my applications.  I was just curious about real reason. Why are not included those libraries in each Windows installation.

Comment: @jhruby: Are you wondering why the Visual C++2010 runtime wasn't distributed with Windows 2000? Lack of timemachines, I'd guess.

Comment: @MSalters When the new VS is realeased they would just push the new runtime  into existing supported Windows throught Windows update. No big deal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a C runtime included with Windows, `msvcrt.dll`.  The MinGW gcc variation uses that library as its base runtime. Microsoft also builds programs that link to that runtime (for example, the programs that are part of the Windows installation).

While the `msvcrt.dll` that is part of Windows has the same name as the runtime DLL from VC6, it's not necessarily the VC6 runtime.  Each new version of Windows has added functions to the `msvcrt.dll` and probably fixed some bugs.

The WDK used to include build configurations to link to `msvcrt.dll` (it looks like the last version of the WDK to support this was WDK 7.1). These build configurations also included some compatibility shims, such as `msvcrt_win2003.obj`,  that allow a program built with such a configuration to run against the `msvcrt.dll` libraries included with older versions of Windows - adding support for newer exception handling and some newer APIs, for example.

I suspect there are various reasons that MS prefers that 3rd party programs link to runtimes that are not part of the Windows system files. A couple possible reasons:

- it helps ensure that the 3rd party programs are not broken by a Windows update that includes a newer version of `msvcrt.dll`.
- it helps ensure that 3rd party programs will run against the runtime DLLs that they were tested against (since presumably the 3rd party program's installer also makes certain that the appropriate MSVC redistributable runtime is installed).